# Console erros innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I seem to be getting console errors on my `innerHTML=t;` the script is to display time on a page. Here is the console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null time.js:8
```

The script is to display time on a page. Here is the code:

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer(event) {
    var d=new Date();
    var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("jstimer").innerHTML=t;
}
```

Does anybody know why I am getting those console errors?

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null time.js:8

because

```
document.getElementById("jstimer")
```

is returning null, meaning that the element was not found.  You need to check your html and make sure that there is in fact an element with the **id** (not class, or name, or anything else) of `jstime` in your dom *at the time this timer fires*